# Laravel Route:POST - Very High CPU Usage

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am testing the Laravel 5.4,
i found something weird.

from a simple hello world function:

```
public function hello(Request $request)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

When doing stress test with aws ec2 m4.large - NGINX PHP-FPM 7,

on GET, i can achieve 
100 - 2000 concurrent users / second in a minute without any error and the CPU usage is still okay ( around 40% ).

on POST,
100 - 200 concurrent users / second is the limit ( 0 error ), and the CPU usage is very high ( 100%).

how to fix the issue? Thank you

Comment: Can you monitor the PID using top or HTOP command on Linux and check what services are running in the case of get / post

Comment: hi @Ali , it's turn out the GET request is cached by nginx and POST not. and is it normal for m4.large ec2 to handle maximum 200 concurrent users without cache ( 98% cpu usage ). thank you